# Search Issues Green Star

Tags: search

On my SharePoint I have items in waterfall type order the items come in are approved or rejected and moved to a Completed or Rejected folder/library. All seems to be working well. However, Ive noticed that some of the items in the Completed folder/library have green stars next to them, to me this indicates they are new or have been updated in someway. The issue Im running into, is that when I attempt to search for these items it gives me a link to the main library that they are in, but doesnt show the link to the completed folder/library, and when I click on the link it gives me a page that says something went wrong. I can search for other items without the green star in the Completed folder/library, just the search for the ones with the star causes this issue. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the items move to a new list or library, then they are new to that list or library, so having the green "new" star is not surprising, it is what we would expect.  As far as the search goes, it sounds like the search crawl is not happening soon enough after the items get moved, so the search index is not updated with the items new location, which is why it gives you the old location.  And then of course when you try to go to the old location, the item is no longer there, and so therefore "something went wrong" when trying to access the item in the old location.

Comment: I am unable to search any document with a green asterisk. Once the asterisk has gone I, and others can search for the document and find it. Is there a reason and a remedy for this?

Comment: How soon a document gets indexed is controlled by the settings for how often the search engine crawls the content.

Comment: How can I find out the frequency of the "search engine crawl"